# How can I add an active class to the carousel thumbnails?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 2.3, and [this example of extending the carousel](http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/carousel-extended), I would like to add an active state to the thumbnails, so as it cycles through, a class of active would be added. Whereas the code I have only works when it is clicked. How can I modify it so that it automatically adds it and also when you click?

I know the code below doesn't match but this is what I have so far.

```
$('.slide-link).click(function() {
    $('.slide-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `slid.bs.carousel` event.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

I'm not sure what the arguments are, but a starter event function containing `console.log(arguments);` should give you info on what it passes to the function, to see if you can get the current active slide to tag it with a class.